# How to show credit card number as star (*) while user is inputting the number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show all the input as stars when the user types in the credit card field except the last four digits which I want to show as numbers. I used jQuery masking but it is not giving me desired result.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? When a user enters his credit card he usually has the card available, i.e. someone watching could just look at the physical card... Masking the digits is just annoying and people won't expect it (pretty much no payment company does it). Besides that, the average human will not be able to remember a credit card number by just seeing it for a few moments (unlike some passwords like "correct horse battery staple" or "123456").

Comment: Not very user-friendly. How is she supposed to check the input before submitting? Showing only ***-1234 for subsequent pages makes sense, but on the input page? What is the benefit?

Comment: how are you supposed to know if it's the correct credit card number? I've never encountered a Online Shop that has this functionality.

Anyway <input type="password" /> should solve it

Comment: With a name like that, I guess @ThiefMaster would know :-)

Comment: <input type="password" /> will not do it, because i want to show the last four digits. I also know this is wrong way but my clients needs it. i told him but he wants this so i m helpless and will have to do this.

Comment: @RavinderSingh isn't credit card numbers usually split up into segments out of 4 digits per segment? Which only would need your last segment to be a normal input?

Comment: Usually when a user inputs the credit card number, the data is shown. Only upon review is the number hidden in the fashion you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use multiple inputs, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".card-number input[type='password']").keyup(function (event) {
            var len = $(this).val().toString().length;
            if (len == 4) {
                $(this).next().focus();
            }
        });

        $(".card-number input[type='button']").click(function () {
            var number = 0;
            $(".card-number input").not("input[type='button']").each(function (index, element) {
                number += $(element).val();
            });
            alert(number);
        });
    });



</script>

<!-- ####-####-####-#### -->
<div class="card-number" >
    <input type="password" value="" maxlength="4" />
    <input type="password" value="" maxlength="4" />
    <input type="password" value="" maxlength="4" />
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" />
    <input type="button" value="go" />
</div>
```

Comment: +1 - This is what I suggested in my answer. I think it works for this scenario and can also be made to enhance UX.

Comment: Beware this can cause Chrome to autofill passwords into the fields, which is increasingly difficult to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to just use 2 input fields.

Otherwise use the following method. This will display the text below the password input field.

http://jsfiddle.net/Doinkmeister/EYgqY/9/

html

```
<input id="creditCard" type="password">

<div id="show"></div>​
```

javascript

```
var number = $('#creditCard');
var display = $('#show');

$('#creditCard').keyup(function(){
    if($('#creditCard').val().length < 1){
        $('#show').text('');
    }
    else{
        var a = '';
        if(number.val().length <= 8){
            for(var i = 0; i < number.val().length; i++){                
                a = a + '*';           
                display.text(a);  
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < number.val().length; i++){ 
                if(i <= 8){
                    a = a + '*';           
                    display.text(a);  
                }
                else{          
                    a = a + number.val().substring(i,i+1);           
                    display.text(a);  
                }
            }
        }
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you need

```js
function creditCardMask(number, character = "*"){
  number = number.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''); /*ensureOnlyNumbers*/
  var l = number.length;
  return number.substring(0,4) + character.repeat(l-8) + number.substring(l-4,l);
}

function doMaskNumber(e){
  document.querySelector("#maskedNumber").innerHTML = creditCardMask(document.querySelector("#credit-card").value);
}
```

```html
Credit card number<input type="text" id="credit-card" value="1111111111">
<p id="maskedNumber"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="doMaskNumber()">Make the mask</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest implementation would start off with an `<input type =password>` and while input is going into that you also write the values into a `<input type=text>` that is hidden then when then user is done entering values change all the characters except the last four to *s and show that box and hide the password box.

Comment: Do not use `<input type =password>` as it will break password managers for your site by asking the user to "save" their password as if it has changed each time they use the site.

Answer (score -1):

You could let this done dynamically:

```
window.onkeyup = function(ev) {

  val = $("the-input").val();
  for(var i = 0;i<min(digits_to_not_show,val.length-1);i++) {
   val = val.substring(0,i)+"*"+val.substr(i+1);
  }

   $("the-input").val(val);
}
```